# how can i link this calculator to a button?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

so I am working on a project currently for a bookeeping software. one part of my code is a tkinter gui which has a button labeled 'calculator'. the that I am having is that I dont know how to connect these 2 parts of code together so that when i click on the calculator button the calculator shown below runs. I have tried using the command function but nothing has worked and i have asked in other places and they suggest doing some things with the files which I have no idea how to do as i have no previous experience with python file tinkering. If anyone could help me it would be great as I'm pretty lost and really need to get this program to work. all suggestions are appreciated, Thank you

```
#the calc:
import tkinter as tk

LARGE_FONT_STYLE = ("Arial", 40, "bold")
SMALL_FONT_STYLE = ("Arial", 16)
DIGITS_FONT_STYLE = ("Arial", 24, "bold")
DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE = ("Arial", 20)

OFF_WHITE = "#F8FAFF"
WHITE = "#FFFFFF"
LIGHT_BLUE = "#CCEDFF"
LIGHT_GRAY = "#F5F5F5"
LABEL_COLOR = "#25265E"


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.geometry("375x667")
        self.window.resizable(0, 0)
        self.window.title("Calculator")

        self.total_expression = ""
        self.current_expression = ""
        self.display_frame = self.create_display_frame()

        self.total_label, self.label = self.create_display_labels()

        self.digits = {
            7: (1, 1), 8: (1, 2), 9: (1, 3),
            4: (2, 1), 5: (2, 2), 6: (2, 3),
            1: (3, 1), 2: (3, 2), 3: (3, 3),
            0: (4, 2), '.': (4, 1)
        }
        self.operations = {"/": "\u00F7", "*": "\u00D7", "-": "-", "+": "+"}
        self.buttons_frame = self.create_buttons_frame()

        self.buttons_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        for x in range(1, 5):
            self.buttons_frame.rowconfigure(x, weight=1)
            self.buttons_frame.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.create_digit_buttons()
        self.create_operator_buttons()
        self.create_special_buttons()
        self.bind_keys()

    def bind_keys(self):
        self.window.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.evaluate())
        for key in self.digits:
            self.window.bind(str(key), lambda event, digit=key: self.add_to_expression(digit))

        for key in self.operations:
            self.window.bind(key, lambda event, operator=key: self.append_operator(operator))

    def create_special_buttons(self):
        self.create_clear_button()
        self.create_equals_button()
        self.create_square_button()
        self.create_sqrt_button()

    def create_display_labels(self):
        total_label = tk.Label(self.display_frame, text=self.total_expression, anchor=tk.E, bg=LIGHT_GRAY,
                               fg=LABEL_COLOR, padx=24, font=SMALL_FONT_STYLE)
        total_label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        label = tk.Label(self.display_frame, text=self.current_expression, anchor=tk.E, bg=LIGHT_GRAY,
                         fg=LABEL_COLOR, padx=24, font=LARGE_FONT_STYLE)
        label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        return total_label, label

    def create_display_frame(self):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.window, height=221, bg=LIGHT_GRAY)
        frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        return frame

    def add_to_expression(self, value):
        self.current_expression += str(value)
        self.update_label()

    def create_digit_buttons(self):
        for digit, grid_value in self.digits.items():
            button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text=str(digit), bg=WHITE, fg=LABEL_COLOR, font=DIGITS_FONT_STYLE,
                               borderwidth=0, command=lambda x=digit: self.add_to_expression(x))
            button.grid(row=grid_value[0], column=grid_value[1], sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def append_operator(self, operator):
        self.current_expression += operator
        self.total_expression += self.current_expression
        self.current_expression = ""
        self.update_total_label()
        self.update_label()

    def create_operator_buttons(self):
        i = 0
        for operator, symbol in self.operations.items():
            button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text=symbol, bg=OFF_WHITE, fg=LABEL_COLOR, font=DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE,
                               borderwidth=0, command=lambda x=operator: self.append_operator(x))
            button.grid(row=i, column=4, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            i += 1

    def clear(self):
        self.current_expression = ""
        self.total_expression = ""
        self.update_label()
        self.update_total_label()

    def create_clear_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="C", bg=OFF_WHITE, fg=LABEL_COLOR, font=DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.clear)
        button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def square(self):
        self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**2"))
        self.update_label()

    def create_square_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="x\u00b2", bg=OFF_WHITE, fg=LABEL_COLOR, font=DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.square)
        button.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def sqrt(self):
        self.current_expression = str(eval(f"{self.current_expression}**0.5"))
        self.update_label()

    def create_sqrt_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="\u221ax", bg=OFF_WHITE, fg=LABEL_COLOR, font=DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.sqrt)
        button.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def evaluate(self):
        self.total_expression += self.current_expression
        self.update_total_label()
        try:
            self.current_expression = str(eval(self.total_expression))

            self.total_expression = ""
        except Exception as e:
            self.current_expression = "Error"
        finally:
            self.update_label()

    def create_equals_button(self):
        button = tk.Button(self.buttons_frame, text="=", bg=LIGHT_BLUE, fg=LABEL_COLOR, font=DEFAULT_FONT_STYLE,
                           borderwidth=0, command=self.evaluate)
        button.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

    def create_buttons_frame(self):
        frame = tk.Frame(self.window)
        frame.pack(expand=True, fill="both")
        return frame

    def update_total_label(self):
        expression = self.total_expression
        for operator, symbol in self.operations.items():
            expression = expression.replace(operator, f' {symbol} ')
        self.total_label.config(text=expression)

    def update_label(self):
        self.label.config(text=self.current_expression[:11])

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    calc = Calculator()
    calc.run()
```

Comment: *"I have tried using the command function but nothing has worked"* What do you mean *"nothing has worked"*? I tried importing `Calculator` in another tkinter application and set `command=Calculator` of a button, it works fine (although it is not recommended to have multiple instances of `Tk`).

Comment: Please try to reduce the example down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code and appears that
1.) there is no `import tkinter` statement at the head of Python file and it appears you've abbreviated it to `tk`. If you are to use it as `tk` then you'll need to import it as `import tkinter as tk`.
2.) At the end of the class `Calculator()` you are calling up the class within itself in an if statement. This throws an undefined variable error.
The official tkinter documentation may be a good place to start for an answer. This part in particular look at the structure in the example. http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html

Comment: yeah sorry thats my bad i didnt quite copy the correct code in but i have edited it now and it should work fine